# Best way to find and select a country

Tags: selection, multi-selection, country

I am trying to find the best way to do a region-to-country selection on a tablet. We came up with two ideas:

1. **Show a world map with regions.** Once the user taps a region, zoom in and show countries with names. There the user can select a country or countries.

   **Advantages**

   This approach allows the user to visually select the region and country. The user can even link the country by dragging a line across the country.

   **Disadvantages**

   It's hard to select a small country and show its name. If the user is not familiar with that part of the world and exactly where the target country exists, the user might have difficulty choosing a region.
2. **Show a list of countries**, [like this example](http://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/)

   **Advantages**

   The country name is shown directly. Region selection, zoom, etc. are bypassed.

   **Disadvantages**

   The user may need to scroll or search, and the UI may not feel as “rich”.

Comment: I'll also add that some people probably don't know where their country is located. Do some research among your personas first to understand the background and academic level.

Comment: How many countries are you planning to have? Will it be worldwide or in concrete region (e.g. Europe)?

Comment: @IgorGubaidulin: It will be the worldwide

Comment: @BartGijssens: This is a system used for providing different type of services so the user need to select the region --> country(s) of their wish and assign services to the country(s).

Comment: Why have you automatically skipped the concept of the drop-down menu? It's important in UI design not to reinvent the wheel, and the drop-down is a perfectly suitable way to present a collection of countries.

Comment: Don't show a map.  [It causes more trouble than it's worth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/22/54679.aspx).

Comment: We need context. What are users selecting a country for in the first place?

Comment: @JonBee well, it's a perfectly suitable way to present a collection countries *in certain contexts*--namely you are picking a country by name. But if you are trying to choose countries by region, and don't know exact regions, the map UI might actually make a whole lot more sense. We just don't have enough information to properly answer this question.

Comment: @Dan: wait, really? How many people cannot locate their home country on a world map?

Comment: If you use a list, consider adding multiple terms for the same country in some cases. It drives me batty when I have to guess whether a UI designer things I live in the United Kingdom, England, Great Britain or Britain, so I have to hunt through multiple places in their damned list.

Comment: @Bergi: Among men and women aged 18 to 24 in the continental United States, one in ten of those with up to a high school education cannot identify the U.S., and one in five cannot find the Pacific Ocean. (http://www.nationalgeographic.com/roper2006/pdf/FINALReport2006GeogLitsurvey.pdf)

Comment: @DanielDeLaney: Thanks, amazing. I guess other population groups than young adult americans don't fare much better then :-/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How about just using a Combo Box?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftdxNO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

By a user being required to just choose what country they are from, it removes the unnecessary step of a user needing to first select the region (or you can just infer the region based on the country selected if needed). Allowing a user to start typing the country they are from will also narrow down the options available to choose from (an advantage over listing all options available in a dropdown list / graphically).

Smashing Magazine wrote an article about [redesigning the way countries can be selected](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/redesigning-the-country-selector/) (they landed on using a combo box too). They documented their design process for this quite nicely too and is worth reading. There's also a [live demo](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector) and a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/JamieAppleseed/selectToAutocomplete).

Comment: I come from a country that is named completely different in English and in its own language and it becomes incredibly annoying to figure out if the language names are all in English or localized because it involves a lot of scrolling and searching the list for something that might not be there. So the perfect solution for a combobox would be to match both English and localized country names even if only one of both is used/shown :)

Comment: @florian: Click the box, start typing the first few letters of the country. If you don't see it, wait 2 seconds and start typing the other variants you are aware of. Much easier than scrolling.

Comment: I would add that the combo box should default to whatever country it auto-detects you in. This will save >90% of users from having to do anything at all.

Comment: I will also point out that the linked example is awesome, but you should be careful about the country names. For instance, Taiwan is listed as `Taiwan, province of China` which is a ***highly* political** statement. Some would say it is part of China, some would say it is an independent nation. In fact, in Mandarin, including the word for country is typical in a country's name, but doing so for Taiwan is a strong statement in and of itself. My point is that country names should be treated with care, since it is bad user experience if the user immediately reads something politically offensive.

Comment: @florianh You're from Germany (Deutschland), no? Try the live demo linked in the answer, and start typing "Deu"

Comment: Also, it's nice touch that starting to type 'England' with 'Eng', yields 1 result: United Kingdom.

Comment: Localization is a must, but I would also suggest using the users IP Address to geolocate the country and either auto select it, or put it at the top of the list. (Another option may be to log where users are from, and put the most popular country at the top).

Comment: The live demo is exactly how I would do it myself, though one minor detail: it's good if it's possible if it's possible to select with the mouse *as well* somehow simply because users are used to that.

Comment: The demo is really cool -- typing `č` (the first letter of `Česko` = `Czechia`) correctly suggests `Czech Republic`. Finally there is someone genuine doing a country selector! :)

Comment: Wow, that demo has a hardcore synonyms list! Not only does typing `B` offer `United Kingdom` (because `Britain` is a synonym), it also offers Germany (because `Bundesrepublik Deutschland` is a synonym)! Kinda strange that synonym-based options are pushed to the ***top*** of the list, not the bottom, though - surely `Bu` should offer Bulgaria, Burundi, etc, and *then* Germany, not Germany first?

Comment: Well, *fairly* hardcore synonyms list. No Burma for Myanmar, no RoC for Taiwan, no Laos for Lao... seems like Europe is very thorough and the rest of the world much less so. Apparently it's based on an international standard, the ISO 3166, so I guess there was a lot of politics behind that list...

Comment: I think many aliases need to be implemented - UK, GB, Great Britain, United Kingdom, England, Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland will all be the same for you.

Comment: @user568458 Not true -- it doesn't push synonyms to the top. It sorts based on a weight factor; Germany is weighted very highly compared to Bulgaria. It just so happens that the only countries for which it provides synonyms (aside from country codes) are those with high weight factors.

Comment: @Dan That's true but it is the official ISO listing (thanks to Chinese influence, basically).  At least it's not "Chinese Taipei."

Comment: @DavidMulder: If you can manage to click in the box (or tab into it) and type a space, you get a classic, scrolling drop-down list, with all the countries in alphabetical order.  Of course, this shows only the canonical names, so, if you’re in London or Liverpool, you have to scroll all the way down to “United Kingdom” (i.e., there is no “Britain”, “England”, or “Great Britain” to click on).  (2) Speaking of which, DannyBeckett: In fact, “en” is enough to bring “United Kingdom” to the top of the list, and then (Enter) selects it.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) A potential glitch or sensitive subject: if you type “korea”, it narrows the list to “Korea, Republic of” and “Korea, Democratic People’s Republic of” (without mentioning “North” or “South”).  Now, I guess, if you live in either of those, you probably know which is which, but if you’re a tourist visiting there, you might not.  Of course typing “no ko” or “so ko” (or other intuitive variants thereof) is enough to select the right one.  … … … … … … … … … …  (@DannyBeckett: I tried to ping you in the above comment, but it wouldn’t let me ping two people in one comment.)

Answer (score 6):

Definitely a dropdown list with the autocomplete (you press C, list scrolls to Czech Republic). One list for a region, the other one below that reacts to first one, for the country. If there is no user need on the region list, ditch it altogether. Country list is essential here.

You don't want a rich UI for something as simple and tedious as a country selection. Users want to go through this step as quick as possible, some without thinking, what you'd call an autopilot, and the more unique the UI will be, the more issues they will have because the UI will interfere with their behavioral pattern.

Ancillary problems with the map selector:

1. Load on a browser
2. Hard to operate on mobile
3. So many clicks more than in the list: click-zoom-zoom-drag-drop-zoom-click-unclick ad nauseam versus click-scroll-click. Any amount of time will be lost, users will not appreciate that.

Comment: Type "A", it scrolls to "Afghanistan" when you wanted "United States".  Type "D", it scrolls to "Denmark" when you wanted "Germany".  Type "B", it scrolls to "Bangladesh" when you wanted "Myanmar".  Type "R", it scrolls to "Russia" when you wanted "Taiwan".  Country names are hard.

Comment: Yes. Such is life. There are multiple countries that start on the same letter.

Comment: @Mark that can be solved with synonyms lists. In fact the linked demo in the top answer has a pretty comprehensive synonym list - type `B` for example, and it gives you United Kingdom (because Britain) and Germany (because Bundesrepublik Deutschland) in addition to the regular `B`s. It's not perfect though - no Burma, no RoC (in fact it has the absurdly pro-PRC `Taiwan, Province of China`), and it quirkily pushes synonym-based options to the front of a list (I'd have them last).

Answer (score 4):

Since it is a tablet device, can't you automatically detect the location? Either from the user profile, or from the location service of the device? You could bring that up as a default selection an a longer list.

Comment: Consider the product is used across the world. the admin will provide different kind of services to different regions.

Comment: This is an excellent point. You could do an IP lookup, which, unless they are using a VPN, proxy, etc, should give you an approximate location (good enough for at least region, and almost always good enough for country). This could, as @Bart Gijssens said, be used as the initially selected option in a drop-down, or other list.

Comment: Well, as long as people are not shopping to their home address while actually abroad etc., or aren't like me (VPNs, forbidden location sharing, etc.) Choosing something for the user because **you** believe that's what the user wants is always bad. This annoys the hell out of me with Google, who do it all the time.

Comment: It would just be a default that could be changed by the users.

Comment: @BartGijssens and then you're back to square one - what's the best UI for users choosing a country when your educated guess gets it wrong? I do agree that picking a sensible default is a good idea, but you still need a good manual UI for the many cases when someone wants to choose a country that's not the one they are currently in (or, *appear* to be in)

Comment: @user568458: True, but the biggest disadvantage of showing a complete list of countries has been reduced. Most users will not have to scroll as the correct selection is on top.

Comment: This is a possible solution if the user is trying to select their own country. I didn't see anything that said that is the case.

Answer (score 4):

1: If we're talking a global system then that's a no. As you say it could be a real pain to zoom right in to Singapore, lots of clicks.

Also don't forget that though it may seem logical to me and you that the USA is that big bit, second one down, on the western land mass, some people REALLY suck at geography.

A lot would depend on exactly what sort of system you're building and how many countries you are including however. If its just a North American system and you've a simple choice of Canada, Mexico or US and there's nice flashy lights and text and flags when you highlight one then it should be OK.

However: Big potential for trouble lies in the execution here. If for instance somebody has their screen set at a high level of zoom these maps tend to go rather awry. Also on mobile they tend to rather suck- its hard to fit the whole world in a vertical screen so I have to click to scroll the map and...agh! No! I'm not in Russia!

2: I do like Apple's use of flags. Lots of people dislike flags, but I love them. They really draw the eye. Of course there could be a potential for controversy if your business is going into some areas (e.g. Taiwan & China), but generally flags=yay from me.

If you're totally global and you're listing every country like this...Then it just won't work. If however you've only a limited selection and it is clearly organised like Apple then its fine.

Be sure however to include a nice big "YOUR COUNTRY ISN'T LISTED?", "International English version", or the like.

3: The most typical way seen is an ugly drop down. They are often more usable than they first appear however with the capacity to type "J" taking me straight down to the vicinity of Jamaica rather 
than having to browse to it.

The biggest criminal act you can commit here is messing with the standard alphabetical order. Putting your one or two key markets at the top- fine. But don't fill the top with 10 countries leaving me to scroll down to S and go "Ey? Where's Sweden?"

4: Free text is a way I am rather fond of. Let people just type and then suggest possibilities. Its a lot quicker for me to just click in "UK" than to have to scroll down to it.

It is even better if it also lets me type "England" and then suggests "United Kingdom" to me.

To make this even better you could combine it with....

5: Detect their country. Its pretty easy to do these days. Auto fill in for them USA if thats where their browser is reading as being from.

HOWEVER do NOT lock them into this. Don't just automatically take them to the American site or whatever- clearly say "We think you're in America, is this right?" and have a little x on the US which lets them then click that and change to where they actually are if need be.

I work  abroad a lot and there's nothing winds me up more than being taken to some local language version of the site rather than the standard one that I want.

Comment: I dislike flags very, very much. I never know whether I'm indicating "the Netherlands" or "Luxembourg", and that's not the only [problematic pair](http://flags.wikia.com/wiki/VexiWiki:Articles/Similar_national_flags). Besides that, there are many flags with a very complicated crest, so you may have to redesign the flags to suit your medium.

Comment: I would not suggest using flags alone. However if you have a list of 40 countries and want to select Luxembourg then even if there are two very similar flags your eye would be drawn to two possibilities rather than the full 40. It is still likely to be helpful for bringing you towards Luxembourg quicker than a pure text list would.

Answer (score 3):

[Smashing Magazine describes a nice solution](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/redesigning-the-country-selector/) based on the results of usability tests.

> It handles typos, various spelling sequences, synonyms and prioritized options.
>   The technically correct term for this would be something like an **“auto-complete text field with loose partial matching, synonyms and weighted results.”**

[Here's the demo.](http://baymard.com/labs/country-selector)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the name you suggest... now it is the official component name in our doc.

Comment: You can shorten its name to ACTFwLPMSaWR.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use one of these methods then use the second one as this method has less critical disadvantages. Add a search bar at the top of the screen to filter records. That way user won't have to scroll all the way down.

Comment: Yes we are more concern about the scroll thanks :)